# How to match strings not containing any word characters between a minus sign and numbers in PL/SQL regexp

Tags: regex, plsql

I have some strings in Oracle where there is a minus sign (not at the beginning but inside the string), followed by a number (int or decimal with dot or comma).
I would like to find these in PLSQL. I have this already, and it's almost perfect:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(string, '-\d+(,|\.)*\d*')
```

I was hoping that it's finding strictly strings like `somestring-11,1` but the problem is, it finds also strings like `somestring-11a1,1` so where there is eventually a non numeric (or word) character between the minus and the numbers. I was trying to use negative lookahead, but unfortunately it's not working:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(string, '-\d+!(\w)(,|\.)*\d*')
```

because `somestring-1`s won't be found either anymore. Could you please point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on your shown samples. Simple explanation would be: using lazy match to match till - then match digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by `,` and followed by 1 or more occurrences of digits.

```
.*?-\d+,\d+
```

[Online regex demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/XdC44r/1/)

Comment: Okay, sorry, my definition was not precise enough. The problem with it was, that if there is no dot or comma, it was findig the second number right after the first one, which is not wanted. I was expecting to find the second number more at the end of the string. Sorry, it's not really easy to define a regex question. But with your help I could find the right syntax, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
(^|\D)-(\d+([,.]*\d+)?)($|\W)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/DdudyX/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3 (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [,.]*                    any character of: ',', '.' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of \3 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \3)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W                       non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                             9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
```